# How do I respond to a job offer if I'm waiting for a university to respond to my application?

Tags: job-offer

I'm waiting for an university(ies) to respond to my admission application. They will all come in by the beginning of June. I have a job offer from a company that I'd love to join **if I don't get into a preferred university.**

However, the job requires me to join this May. I'm fairly confident of my university applications. But as mentioned, I'd love to join this company if I don't get in. How do I handle this? I don't want to leave in just under 2 months after I join.

Comment: `I don't want to leave in just under 2 months after I join.`.why?

Comment: I was wondering if that would seem wrong on my part. Wouldn't that annoy the HR executives a bit if I did that?

Comment: That's one of the reason companies have probation period with relaxed terms for termination / quitting. The company evaluates you, as well as you also get a chance to evaluate the company and the work environment, and if things don't work out, the separation is easier.

Comment: I applied long back, and I got this offer a couple of days ago. I didn't have a plan per se; I thought if I don't get into a preferred university, it'll be better join this company. It's a good opportunity and it'll take at least a few months for me to get something like this again if I let this pass (and don't get into my university of choice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a silver bullet to this problem. You have to chose one over the other.

Check one thing: If you join the company now, is there anything in the contract that explicitly prohibits you from leaving after two months (like, a fixed service tenure bond)? If not, I'd suggest, you accept the job offer, continue the job while waiting for the university results to come out.

- If the results are positive **and** the initial two-months of profession experience tells you to go for the university, resign from the job and join the university.
- If the results are negative **or** the initial two-months of profession experience tells you to continue with the job, you got yourself covered.

Comment: I think it's important to note that if OP accepts, then leaves after two months (and they know OP accepted the job under those conditions), they risk burning a bridge. If they'd like to work there in the future again, doing this might make this more complicated, if not impossible. Not saying it will, but it is a real possibility that OP needs to be aware of and consider.

Comment: @MlleMei That's right, but why the company needs to know the reason for leaving? It can very well be one of the canned responses, right?

Comment: True, but if they do apply there later on, I guess OP is going to put his studies ? If OP doesn't intend to work there later on, then there's nothing to lose, I agree.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason why I was hesitant to join and then quit if I get into a good university. But I guess I'm willing to burn that one bridge now. @MlleMei